# How to make Map Optional on whether its every optional value is present

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Map with many Optional values:

```java
Map<MyCoolKey, Optional<MyCoolValue>>
```

I would like to transform this Map into an `Optional<Map<>>`:

```java
Optional<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>>
```

- If every `Optional<MyCoolValue>` is present: the `Optional<Map<>>` should be present.
- If *any* `Optional<MyCoolValue>` is non-present: the `Optional<Map<>>` should be non-present.

I attempted this, and I suspect that my code will work, but it's a bit long-winded:

```java
final Map<MyCoolKey, Optional<MyCoolValue>> myCoolMap;
final Optional<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>> optionalMap = myCoolMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e
                        .getValue()
                        .flatMap(value -> Optional.<Map.Entry<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>>of(
                                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                                        e.getKey(),
                                        value
                                )
                        ))
                )
                .collect(
                        () -> Optional.<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>>of(new HashMap<>()),
                        (optAcc, optEntry) -> optAcc.flatMap(
                                acc -> optEntry.map(
                                        entry -> {
                                            acc.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                                            return acc;
                                        })
                        ),
                        (optAcc1, optAcc2) -> optAcc1.flatMap(
                                acc1 -> optAcc2.map(
                                        acc2 -> {
                                            acc1.putAll(acc2);
                                            return acc1;
                                        }
                                )
                        )
                );
```

Is there a better way to do this? "Better" means correctness, performance, beauty. I would prefer an answer that can do the whole operation in one stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of pure stream solution (without `if`s and ternary operators)

```
final Map<MyCoolKey, Optional<MyCoolValue>> myCoolMap = new HashMap<>();

Optional<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>> output = Optional.of(myCoolMap)
    .filter(map -> map.values().stream().allMatch(Optional::isPresent))
    .map(map -> map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            entry -> entry.getValue().get()
        ))
    );
```

It's not over-complicating - filtering and mapping are what's streams are for!

Comment: I like the idea of filtering optionals. I've accepted this as the answer, because it's a short, readable stream, with acceptable (linear) performance. if your domain commonly includes optional values, then this solution takes advantage of early-exit. downside is that when there's no optionals, you iterate the whole map twice. but that's still linear time, and streams make it trivially parallelisable.

Answer (score 2):

The following method does the job:

```
Map<MyCoolKey, Optional<MyCoolValue>> input;
Optional<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>> output = convertMapWithOptionals(input);
```

where I came up with two "flavors" of this method:

1) Reluctant: first check all, then start converting

```
<K, V> Optional<Map<K, V>> convertMapWithOptionals(Map<K, Optional<V>> map) {
    if (!map.values().stream().allMatch(Optional::isPresent)) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().get()
    )));
}
```

2) Eager: start converting and abort when necessary

```
<K, V> Optional<Map<K, V>> convertMapWithOptionals(Map<K, Optional<V>> map) {
    Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, Optional<V>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (!entry.getValue().isPresent()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get());
    }
    return Optional.of(result);
}
```

Comment: To the downvoter: please, explain the reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand question right, you can use `reduce` instead of `collect`. It would allows you to change `accumulator` during collect.

```
    Optional<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>> optionalMap = myCoolMap
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .reduce(Optional.<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>>of(new HashMap<>()),
                    (acc, entry) -> {
                        if (!acc.isPresent()) {
                            return acc;
                        }
                        if (!entry.getValue().isPresent()) {
                            return Optional.empty();
                        }
                        acc.get().put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get());
                        return acc;
                    },
                    (acc, acc1) -> {
                        if (acc.isPresent() && acc1.isPresent()) {
                            acc.get().putAll(acc1.get());
                            return acc;
                        }
                        return Optional.empty();
                    }
            );
```

Comment: I find this solution really unintuitive and unreadable, even though there is some value in its returning `Optional.empty()` as soon as the first empty value is seen (this solution does *not* short-circuit, though, so even when it already knows the result will be `Optional.empty()` it has to iterate all the remaining values).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski Whether the non-short-circuting is a problem also depends on the circumstances: If an empty optional in the map is a rare case, you might still benifit from skipping the inital `allMatch` iteration vs the rare instance when you unecessarily check `isEmpty` a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've over-complicated it by trying to put all the logic in a stream. Just filter out the empty `Optional`s and see whether the number of elements is the same:

```
Optional<Map<MyCoolKey, MyCoolValue>> result = Optional.of(
    map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get())
        )
)
.filter(x-> x.size() == map.size());
```

Comment: So if this map is 10000 items long, you want to map it anyway, and **then** check whether you want to return it or not?

Comment: @Danon Your solution will iterate over all elements twice. A simple unnecessary mapping is not more expensive than that. This puts more on the stack for the entries but premature optimisation is the root of all evil, so who cares. Also 10,000 items is nothing

Comment: Michael, you could inline it into one statement: `result = Optional.of(<yourStream>).filter(tmp -> tmp.size() == map.size())`

Comment: @MalteHartwig Yeah, I like that better than the ternary actually. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael I agree with @Danon. Note that if the map has a lot of elements, you're going to collect the entire map even if the first value is `Optional.empty()` instead of using [`Stream.allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which is a short-circuiting operation (so it would not test all the remaining elements).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski True, I hadn't thought about the short-circuiting, but you're making assumptions that performance is even a relevant concern. Readability is **always** #1. There's not much in it between mine and Danon's but I'd argue that my solution is the most readable. Mine's certainly more readable than yours. If performance is all you care about, you should be hand-optimising assembly.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski The non-short-circuting is no reason for a downvote imo. Let Op decide which solution best fits their needs. Michael's and Vlad's solutions need only one iteration (which is good if the Optionals are hardly ever empty), while Danon's and Tomasz' solutions favor fail-fast behavior (good if Optionals are fairly often empty).

Comment: I definitely agree that readability is #1 :) I fixed the readability of my solution by extracting it into a method, but I agree that it might not be the most readable. However, I find @Danon's solution more readable than yours (his solution is simply more explicit, while yours is a bit more lika a hack).

Comment: @MalteHartwig Now that I carefully read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), I think you might be right that it's not a reason for a downvote. Michael's answer is absolutely far from "egregiously sloppy" - I downvoted it in the spirit of "don't use this, use another solution", but maybe I shouldn't have. As to choosing, however, I think an approach like "start building a new map until you come across an `Optional.empty()`" would still be much better than unnecessarily building an entire filtered `Map`.

Comment: @Michael I cannot take back my downvote until the answer is edited. Would you mind adding a short note that your solution should be used only when: 1) the original map rarely contains empty `Optional`s, **or** 2) performance is not a relevant concern?